# Joining two different MySQL result queries by appending new column

Tags: mysql, ms-access

i would appreciate help to find a way how to combine/join two simple SQL queries using WHERE and IN as a requirement.

Simply, i want the result of this query:

```
SELECT Nationality, MAX(ActorName) as Oldest,
FROM ACTOR 
WHERE BirthDate IN
(SELECT MIN(BirthDate) as MinBday FROM ACTOR GROUP BY Nationality)
GROUP BY Nationality
```

Which results in this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| nationality| oldest       |
+------------+--------------+
| american   | brad pitt    |
+------------+--------------+
| british    | pierce bro   |
+------------+--------------+
| italian    | monica bellu |
+------------+--------------+
```

to be joined with the result of this query:

```
SELECT Nationality, MAX(ActorName) as Oldest,
FROM ACTOR 
WHERE BirthDate IN
(SELECT MAX(BirthDate) as MinBday FROM ACTOR GROUP BY Nationality)
GROUP BY Nationality
```

Which results in this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| nationality| youngest     |
+------------+--------------+
| american   | angelina j   |
+------------+--------------+
| british    | jason stat   |
+------------+--------------+
| italian    | paul gia     |
+------------+--------------+
```

in order to have a resulting table as follows:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
|nationality | oldest       | youngest     |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| american   | brad pitt    | angelina j   |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| british    | pierce bro   | jason stat   |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| italian    | monica bellu | paul gia     |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

note: the only difference between the 2 queries is **MIN**(birthdate) for oldest birthdate, and **MAX**(birthdate) for youngest birthdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very ugly sql can be following, not the most efficient, just a approach.

```
SELECT
    t1.Nationality, t1.Oldest, t2.youngest
FROM (
    SELECT Nationality, MAX(ActorName) as Oldest -- ,
    FROM ACTOR 
    WHERE BirthDate IN
    (SELECT MIN(BirthDate) as MinBday FROM ACTOR GROUP BY Nationality)
    GROUP BY Nationality
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT Nationality, MAX(ActorName) as youngest
    FROM ACTOR 
    WHERE BirthDate IN
    (SELECT MAX(BirthDate) as MaxBday FROM ACTOR GROUP BY Nationality)
    GROUP BY Nationality
) t2 ON t1.Nationality = t2.Nationality
```

Or try this(not tested):

```
SELECT 
    Nationality, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN BirthDate = t1.MinBday THEN ActorName ELSE NULL END) as Oldest,
    MAX(CASE WHEN BirthDate = t1.MaxBday THEN ActorName ELSE NULL END) as youngest
FROM ACTOR
JOIN (
    SELECT Nationality, MIN(BirthDate) as MinBday, MAX(BirthDate) as MaxBday
    FROM ACTOR GROUP BY Nationality) t
ON ACTOR.Nationality = t.Nationality
GROUP BY Nationality
```

Comment: was hoping for a straightforward (even if ugly) answer like this would work, but i failed to mention i am doing this in MS access and for someone reason queries like this always end up with: `Syntax error in FROM clause`

Comment: @jmigdelacruz Updated my answer, just one more comma before `from`.

Comment: thanks @forward! the first query works well. just changed, `join` to `left join` and removed the `-- ,` from `Oldest -- ,`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the birthdate and can join with that directly like

```
SELECT a.Nationality, MAX(a.ActorName) as Oldest,
FROM ACTOR a
JOIN (SELECT Nationality, 
 MIN(BirthDate) as MinBday,
 MAX(BirthDate) as MaxBday
  FROM ACTOR 
  GROUP BY Nationality) xxx
ON a.Nationality = xxx.Nationality
AND (a.BirthDate = xxx.MinBday OR a.BirthDate = xxx.MaxBday)
GROUP BY Nationality;
```